# How to run a function before jQuery validate plugin does the validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validation plugin. I need to remove some design elements from the form before validation occurs (long story). Anyway I can't find any methods that will allow me to do this. The closest I found is the `submitHandler` option:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler

But this fires **after** validation right before the form is submitted by the plugin if the validation is successful. I need to do some things **before** the validation even occurs that need to fire whether the  form validated successfully or not. Is there an option for this plugin that allows for that?

Comment: what does `do some things` mean specifically?

Comment: The request is confusing.  You need to do something before validation but then you say you _"need to fire whether the form validated successfully or not"_.  How can you do something _before_ validation while also doing validation?

Comment: There are lots of callback options for this plugin.  Please be more specific about what you're doing.

Comment: So do some things just means removing some design elements from the form. I want to remove these design elements when the user attempts to submit the form for the first time and I don't want them to come back. So obviously the form can either validate or not validate, the function I want to execute on that first attempt should fire despite the validation outcome. That's all I meant.

Comment: In other words `submitHandler` will work if the form validates, but what if it doesn't, is there a callback that will fire on fail?

Comment: Yes, the `invalidHandler` is the opposite of the `submitHandler`.  It's clearly documented on the same page you've linked:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler

Comment: Like said Sparky. But maybe you could just use in your case: `$(':submit').on('click', function(){$(this).closest('form')...});`

Comment: There's no need to use an external click handler with this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky Surely, i don't know this plugin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if by "validation", you mean when the messages are displayed, you can use these callback functions to get out in front of those.

The `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions toggle the error/valid classes on the input elements and labels.  You can over-ride these to do whatever you want.

The `errorPlacement` callback function is what places the message for each element.  Again, you can override this to do whatever you want.  (You could prevent the placement of messages until your "other things" are done.)

---

The `invalidHandler` callback function is the opposite of the `submitHandler` and it fires upon submit when the form is invalid.

Refer to documentation for all callback functions:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: @TK123, I'm glad I could help.  However, it doesn't really meet the requirement where you're asking for something to fire _before_ it does the validation.  When `invalidHandler` fires, the validation has already occurred, otherwise, it wouldn't know the form was invalid.